# How to remove margin header in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

I started using biblatex for manuscript writing, since removing url and doi information from Mendeley .bib files seemed like a strenuous task. Questions and answers here have been a great help to get me started. However, I am struggling to remove the top margin header for the `\printbibliography`, which is automatically added with a following preamble command:

```
\usepackage[
backend = bibtex,
    citestyle=authoryear,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false,natbib=true,maxbibnames=99,
    maxcitenames=2,
    firstinits
 ]{biblatex}
```

The only way I managed to remove the margin header was by forcing some white space into the bibliography title and adding a References section.

```
\section*{References}
\printbibliography[title= \vspace{0.8cm}]
```

However, this introduces some horizontal white space between "References" title and the reference list. I am sure that there is a proper way doing this, but as a LaTeX beginner, I am having a hard time understanding the Biblatex manual. Could someone tell me how to remove bibliography top margin header, please?

Comment: Would you please add a MWE? It's important to know what class you're using. It's not clear what you mean by "top margin header".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a bibliography with the title "references", formatted as if it were a section head, but not added to running heads (or, given the method you are using, the table of contents).

In that case, first define a new bibliography heading style, thus:

```
\defbibheading{myheading}[References]{%
  \section*{#1}}
```

And then use that as the `heading` option to the bibliography:

```
\printbibliography[heading=myheading]
```

If you want to add this to the table of contents, but not to the page headers, add

```
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
```

within your heading definition.

Comment: Yes. You understood correctly and the solution works perfectly. Thank you and sorry for not providing MWE.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why split the `\defbibheading` command over two lines, with the `%` at the end of the first line?