# Remove heading from biblatex and show chapter in toc numbered

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents

This is a follow up question of this one: [How to remove margin header in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79612/how-to-remove-margin-header-in-biblatex)

Using the scrreprt document class in combination with biblatex leads to the undesired heading for the reference chapter. Using the solution from the link above, I am able to remove the undesired heading. Showing the references in the table of contents works as well, but unfortunately this particular chapter is no longer numbered. 
Below I have included a MWE as well as an example entry of the .bib file.

```
\documentclass[toc=listofnumbered]{scrreprt}
\RequirePackage[sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\defbibheading{myheading}[References]{\chapter*{#1} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography[heading=myheading]

\end{document}


@article{test,
author = {Author, A. and Author B.},
journal = {itle of journal},
number = {8},
pages = {475--478},
volume = {294},
year = {1961}
}
```

Comment: Well, you added there a starred version of `\chapter*`, which removes the numbering.

Comment: bibliography=totocnumered

Comment: @Johannes_B, you are right, there are better ways to do this (I changed my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a numbered version of the "References" chapter you could use:

```
\defbibheading{myheading}[References]{\chapter{#1}}
```

The starred version of `\chapter*` removes the numbering. It also removes the entry from TOC, that's why you had to add it manually latter. Just using the regular version of `\chapter` sorts both things.

Testing your MWE, with the `scrreprt` documentclass, this definition, as far as I can see, reaches your desired results. In a class such as `book` you would probably have to set the heading manually, e.g. by adding `\markboth{}{}` to the definition.

Comment: This is great. I wasn't aware that one can use "heading=" multiple times

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to use `heading` multiple times. Only the last `heading` takes effect.`\printbibliography[title=References, heading=bibnumbered]` will have exactly the same effect.

Comment: @gusbrs I was finally able to test the solution you suggested. For me it leads to the chapter being numbered correctly and listed in the toc. Unfortunately, the undesired heading on the second page of the bibliography remains.

Comment: @leandriis, I didn't grasp this from my initial read of the original post. I though you meant all the way the chapter/section heading. Do you mean also the _page_ heading? Did your original approach succeed in removing that heading for you? (I can revert to the first answer I gave if it is what works).

Comment: @leandriis, by the way, moewe is of course right.

Comment: Sorry for asking my question unprecisely. The chapter heading/title was fine. I just wanted to get rid of the page heading as I don't use them in all the other chapters.
Removing the * from `\chapter*{#1}` leads to the output I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Ok, in rereading the question after your comment, I see that I could have understood it in this direction as well. I'll revert to the initial answer then, given that's what gets the job done.

Comment: If `\chapter` is what the OP wants, they should simply use the option `bibliography=totocnumbered` to `scrreprt` as Johannes suggested. Then there is no need to redefine anything (except for `\refname`/`\bibname`, but that can be done with `title=\refname` as well).

Comment: @moewe, I'm thinking within my boundaries which, in this case, means the possibilities of `biblatex`. I'm curious about it, but not that well acquainted with KOMA. And I tried to make sense of Johannes suggestion, but couldn't go trough. If you or him could provide another answer in these lines, I'd be glad to see it as well.

Comment: Well, I could go trough now with your comment. But I still leave it for you guys, for the credit is fully yours in this case.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it then (as CW).

Answer (score 2):

Following Johannes_B initial suggestion, reinforced and elaborated by moewe, you should use `scrreprt`'s class option `bibliography=totocnumered`. Like this:

```
\documentclass[toc=listofnumbered,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp,autocite=superscript]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=\refname]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @leandriis, if this indeed works for you (as I believe it does), I recommend that you accept this one as the answer to the question. Of course, I recommend that you use it too. If a direct option is available for your purpose, it is in general preferable to use it, rather than go about redefining macros and so on.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and answers. Unfortunately this solution does not work for my original document while defining an new bibheading does. It seems that I have forgotten an important part of the code while trying to create an MWE. I will have a closer look on my code later and see if I can find out what causes this strange behaviour in my original document.